# Android Preferences Screen inside Action Bar Tab

Tags: tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-preferences

I am developing some app with have ActionBar with three tabs, one of with is a settings tab.
PreferencesFragment loads my preferences xml file, so how can i add `PreferenceFragment` to `ActionBar` Tab ??

**As at this picteur:**

This is a main Activity that adds three tabs, I has added two simple fragments tab successfuly but a problem began with a RreferenceFragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab settings = actionBar.newTab();
    settings.setText("Settings");
    settings.setTabListener(new SettingsFragment());
    actionBar.addTab(settings);

    Tab control = actionBar.newTab();
    control.setText("Controller");
    control.setTabListener(new ControlFragment());
    actionBar.addTab(control);

    Tab information = actionBar.newTab();
    information.setText("information");
    information.setTabListener(new InformationFragment());
    actionBar.addTab(information);

}
```

**For example, this is a ControlFragment class ( second tab )**

```
public class ControlFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private Fragment fragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.control_fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction frgTransaction) {
    //TODO
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction frgTransaction) {
    fragment = new ControlFragment();
    frgTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    frgTransaction.attach(fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction frgTransaction) {
    frgTransaction.remove(fragment);
}
```

}

**And this is a SettingsFragment class with do the main problem**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private Activity act;
private Context context;
private Fragment fragment;

public SettingsFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_settings);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    arg1.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    arg1.attach(fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Application crashes because its a problem to transact `PreferenceFragment`.

**How I can inplement it ??? I know about TabHost but I use Action Bar.**

Comment: Hi, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the v13 support library to achieve this. Hope I helped.